# Reading kallsyms in user-mode

Tags: linux, kernel, symbols

i'm writing the code about low-level stuff. i need to know kernel symbol addresses to write reliable code. So im trying to read the kallsyms when im in user-mode in Ubuntu kernel-3.0.19. and that's kallsyms output in user-mode.

...
00000000 r __ksymtab_prepare_kernel_cred
00000000 r __kcrctab_prepare_kernel_cred
00000000 r __kstrtab_prepare_kernel_cred
...

how can i solve this problem in user-mode. when im root and everyting's ok but that's not what i need.

thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It is intentional that `/proc/kallsyms` shows zeros instead of the real addresses for a non-root user. This lowers the security risk a bit.

The details are available in [this upstream commit](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=455cd5ab305c90ffc422dd2e0fb634730942b257). See also how `%pK` print specifier is used in [s_show() function in kallsyms.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kallsyms.c?v=3.0#L501), `s_show` being responsible for providing a record in `/proc/kallsyms`.

I doubt it is still possible to get symbol addresses somehow without being a root user. One can not access `System.map` without root privileges either. Same for writing to `/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict`.

Comment: `One can not access System.map without root privileges either`. On my RHEL server it is allowed to read this file /boot/System.map-...

Comment: Depends on the distro and/or the kernel version, I guess. If System.map contains the addresses of the kernel functions and is readable to a non-root user by default, this actually makes the protection of kallsyms useless. If it is RHEL 6, the kernel is likely to be 2.6.32, IIRC, where /proc/kallsyms was not protected. So readable System.map file does not increase the security risks in that case.

Comment: If you're using a kernel compiled by the distribution, you could just see the distribution archives for appropriate System.map, no?

Comment: @domen: good point. Yes, you usually can. And it may weaken security significantly unless something like address space layout randomization comes into play. The latter is also [not a panacea](http://forums.grsecurity.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3367) though.