# Allow single user to access /proc/kallsyms

Tags: linux-kernel

This file is readable for all users: `/proc/kallsyms`

This file contains addresses for each kernel symbol (when i am root)

but when i am a classic user, i only see 0x00000000 address.

Is there a way to allow a classic user to see the addresses (i am root on the computer)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading kallsyms in user-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447491/reading-kallsyms-in-user-mode)

Comment: `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict`

Comment: This is not true, i have tried to put 0 in this file and it does not change anything. I still have 0x00000 addresses with my non-root user

Answer (score 3):

As the source code snippet posted by Jonathon Reinhart shows, regular users can view the addresses in `/proc/kallsyms` when both `/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict` *and* `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` are set to `0`.

The following works for me on Kernel version 5.3.0:

```
$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict > /dev/null
$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid > /dev/null
$ head /proc/kallsyms
```

Answer (score 1):

The [kernel documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/869e3305f23dfeacdaa234717c92ccb237815d90/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt#L416-L437) says:

```
kptr_restrict:

This toggle indicates whether restrictions are placed on
exposing kernel addresses via /proc and other interfaces.

When kptr_restrict is set to 0 (the default) the address is hashed before
printing. (This is the equivalent to %p.)

When kptr_restrict is set to (1), kernel pointers printed using the %pK
format specifier will be replaced with 0's unless the user has CAP_SYSLOG
and effective user and group ids are equal to the real ids. This is
because %pK checks are done at read() time rather than open() time, so
if permissions are elevated between the open() and the read() (e.g via
a setuid binary) then %pK will not leak kernel pointers to unprivileged
users. Note, this is a temporary solution only. The correct long-term
solution is to do the permission checks at open() time. Consider removing
world read permissions from files that use %pK, and using dmesg_restrict
to protect against uses of %pK in dmesg(8) if leaking kernel pointer
values to unprivileged users is a concern.

When kptr_restrict is set to (2), kernel pointers printed using
%pK will be replaced with 0's regardless of privileges.
```

Whether or not `/proc/kallsyms` shows actual symbol values is controlled by [`kallsyms_show_value`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/869e3305f23dfeacdaa234717c92ccb237815d90/kernel/kallsyms.c#L637-L659) in `kernel/kallsyms.c`:

```c
/*
 * We show kallsyms information even to normal users if we've enabled
 * kernel profiling and are explicitly not paranoid (so kptr_restrict
 * is clear, and sysctl_perf_event_paranoid isn't set).
 *
 * Otherwise, require CAP_SYSLOG (assuming kptr_restrict isn't set to
 * block even that).
 */
int kallsyms_show_value(void)
{
    switch (kptr_restrict) {
    case 0:
        if (kallsyms_for_perf())
            return 1;
    /* fallthrough */
    case 1:
        if (has_capability_noaudit(current, CAP_SYSLOG))
            return 1;
    /* fallthrough */
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So if you are a normal user without any [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), you cannot see kernel symbol values.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you are writing a (compiled) application, you can could apply the `CAP_SYSLOG` file capability to your executable.

Comment: I have put 0 in /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict and i still see 000000 addresses. I am not trying to accomplish anything, i just want to understand

Comment: i have tried to type this: it does not change anything sudo /sbin/setcap 'cap_syslog+ep' /bin/bash